# What can be the code for someIEnumerable.Select extension method?

Tags: c#, linq, yield

I am new in `LINQ` and would like to write some extension methods. Before doing so I wanted to test if I will do it correctly. I just wanted to compare the performance of my `CustomSelect` extension method with built-in `Select` extension method.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<int> list = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        list.Add(i);

    DateTime now1 = DateTime.Now;
    List<int> process1 = list.Select(i => i).ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now - now1);

    DateTime now2 = DateTime.Now;
    List<int> process2 = list.CustomSelect(i => i).ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now - now2);
}

public static IEnumerable<TResult> CustomSelect<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TResult> selector)
{
    foreach (TSource item in source)
    {
        yield return selector(item);
    }
}
```

Timespan for built-in method: 0.18 sec
Timespan for custom method: 0.35 sec

Changing the order of processes yields the same result.
If I collect the elements in a list and `return` instead of `yield return`, then the timespan is being nearly same with built-in one. But as far as I know we should `yield return` whereever possible.

So what can be the code for built-in method? What should be my approach?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The code for `Enumerable` is [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs).

Comment: are you perhaps running in debug mode and/or inside the debugger? (never test performance inside the debugger, unless you know exactly what you are doing)

Comment: You might also be interested in [EduLinq](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Edulinq/default.aspx), Jon Skeet's worked reimplementation LINQ to Objects - or you might be interested in avoiding it :)

Comment: @MarcGravell I wans't in debugger but `Debug` was selected in `Solution Configuration` if it means it was in `Debug Mode`. Performance really changed when i changed it to `Release`. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key difference I can see is that the inbuilt method checks for `List<T>` and special-cases it, exploiting the custom `List<T>.Enumerator` implementation, rather than `IEnumerable<T>` / `IEnumerator<T>`. You can do that special-case yourself:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> CustomSelect<TSource, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TResult> selector)
{
    if (source is List<TSource>)
        return CustomSelectList((List<TSource>)source, selector);
    return CustomSelectDefault(source, selector);
}
private static IEnumerable<TResult> CustomSelectList<TSource, TResult>(
    List<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TResult> selector)
{
    foreach (TSource item in source)
    {
        yield return selector(item);
    }
}
private static IEnumerable<TResult> CustomSelectDefault<TSource, TResult>(
    IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TResult> selector)
{
    foreach (TSource item in source)
    {
        yield return selector(item);
    }
}
```

You could take that a stage further by hand-rolling the entire iterator (which is what `WhereSelectListIterator<TSource, TResult>` does), but the above is probably close enough.

The inbuilt implementation also special-cases arrays, and handles various forms of composed queries.

Comment: Changing the mode to `Release` differed very much as you said. And also chacking for `List<T>.Enumerator` is better. Using `WhereSelectListIterator` was best.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of things wrong with your performance test, which makes it inconclusive - you should look into best practices for benchmarking code in .NET. Use `Stopwatch` instead of `DateTime.Now`, use many repetitions of the same thing on at once instead of one shot at each, make sure you're not getting hindered by the GC (`.ToList()` is going to screw your measurements quite a bit).

`yield return` should not be used because it's faster, the idea is that it's easy to write, and it's lazy. If I did `Take(10)` on the `yield return` variant, I'd only get 10 elements. The `return` variant, on the other hand, will produce the whole list, return it, and *then* reduce it to 10 elements.

In effect, you're taking pretty much the simplest case where there's very little reason to use `Select` at all (apart from clarity). Enumerables are made to handle far more crazier stuff, and using the LINQ methods, do it in easy to understand and concise matter, exposing an interface familiar to functional programmers. That often means that you could get more performance by rewriting the whole thing in a less general way - the point is that you should really only do that if *necessary* - if this is not a performance bottleneck of your application (and it rarely will be), the cleaner, easier to extend code is a better option.